# Pre and post on Java. Not taking effect?

Tags: java, int, post-increment, pre-increment

```
int x = 12;     
int y = 15;      
while (y >= 0)     
{      
     x = x--;     
     y = --y;     
}      
System.out.print(x);
```

This prints out 12 and I'm guessing x is never changed because it's stored before the post (x--) takes effect, but why does x-- never take effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--` in `x--` does take effect. However, you do not see it, because you assign the value of pre-decrement `x` right back into `x`.

Here is what happens when you do `x = x--`:

- The value of `x` gets stored into a temporary space (say, `tempX`)
- One is subtracted from `x`
- New value is assigned back into `x`
- Once the right-hand side has finished computing, `tempX` is assigned back to `x`

This produces the overall effect of `x` not being changed.

The effect of `y = --y` differs because the value of the expression `--y` is the same as the value of `y` after the decrement, so the overall effect is the same as `--y`.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, `x = x--;` does the following:

1. Load variable `x` to the operand stack (value is `12`).
2. Decrement `x`, its value is now `11`.
3. Store the value loaded in step 1 back to `x` ==> `x` goes back to `12`.